# Kruskal-Wallis or Friedman

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

I have 3 groups of 30 fish.

```
group 1: without anaesthesia
group 2: clove oil anaesthesia
group 3: MS-222 anaesthesia
```

Every group was investigated at six levels of time (0, 0.5, 1, 2, 6 and 24 hours after anaesthesia). The data aren't normal. Which test to use? Kruskal-Wallis or Friedman?

Comment: What is your exact research question? Do you want to check all 6 levels of time or only the final level with respect to initial level? What exactly are you testing? Is the outcome variable a numeric one or categorical / ordered? Add more details to your question.

Comment: I want to compare all 6 levels of time in within and between groups. In fact, I want to compare the effects of different methods of anesthesia on the number of the specific cells.

Comment: Graphical methods may be the best for this. If you post some sample data here, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly spoken you use the **Kruskal-Wallis** test if the data has **unmatched pairs** and the **Friedman-test** is the data has **matched pairs**.

In my opinion the data of the three tests is **unmatched**. Therefore the Kruskal-Wallis test is the better test.